# Elixir Phoenix web console

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Coming from the Rails world, I love the "Web console" debugger feature: https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/8fqdg0/web_console_is_not_longer_showing_up_on_rails_52/

[image: web console]

Is there a way to have this in Elixir with Phoenix?

Since sockets are already there, and there is a nice web debug interface, it should be piece of cake to have it, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think there is something like that, but with the release of Phoenix LiveView, that should be a easy feature to implement. https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-liveview-is-now-live/20889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't exists.

Discussion with José Valim:

> José: So we have implementations of IEx over websockets but we can't provide the same feature set as Ruby in that you will have a webconsole **at the error site**. In that case, I am not sure if the feature is that useful.
>
> Me: IEx over websockets looks great and really matches what I was imagining. Then I guess, to implement this, there should be some kind of error-catching behavior over the server that triggers iex and the socket server at any error level, shouldn't it?
>
> José: This is exactly what I meant. This is not possible in Elixir/Phoenix.

Thanks for being open to discussion José!